# Is it possible to improve efficiency of this iterative algorithm?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, algorithm

I am a researcher looking into vehicle parking behaviour and parking occupancy patterns. I am trying to write an efficient and robust algorithm to calculate parking occupancy over time.

Here is my story:

I have the parking data recorded using in-ground parking sensors from across the city of Melbourne, Australia. You can view the data here: https://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/Transport/Parking-Events-From-Parking-Bays-With-Sensors/8nfq-mtcn?.

My initial task is to plot this data as a time series plot so I can visually analyse trends in parking occupancy over different periods of time (day, week, month etc).

There are 7,112 sensors installed in various streets of the city. Each sensor records data when a car arrives and departs the parking spot (lets call it an “event”). From 2011 to 2012, they have recorded 12,208,417 events. Every event is a row in the database and has the following columns that interest me:

- sensor ID
- arrival time
- departure time
- duration of parking
- the street where this sensor is located

Now, I don't want to plot data from every sensor separately but the group of sensors that belong to a street over fixed intervals of time (seconds, minutes, hours, etc). So, street “A” might have 10 parking spots (= 10 sensors), street “B” = 12 sensors and so on.

For a 24 hour time series plot between (10/10/2011 12:00:00 AM) to (11/10/2011 12:00:00 AM) for a given street “A”, here is what I have done:

**USING SQL**

1. Retrieve all events by the sensors located in street "A" between the given dates by running SQL query

**USING PHP**

2. Iterate over a time loop from (10/10/2011 12:00:00 AM) to (11/10/2011 12:00:00 AM) with a 1 minute offset over every iteration.
3. Begin parsing data:

— Foreach minute (time sample):

—— foreach sensor in street “A”

——— foreach event

———— if this event was recorded by the current sensor AND time sample lies between car arrival AND departure time, THEN add +1 to occupancy for this minute

---

Stats about runtime:

- SQL query time: ~260ms
- PHP exec time: 33.1s
- Number of time samples: 1,440 (i.e. the number of minutes in a 24 hour cycle)
- Number of sensors the algorithm had to deal with: 49
- Number of events the algorithm had to deal with: 508

I was able to get info on how many cars were parked on a street at a given minute so I can easily plot it using a line chart.

I have a feeling that my algorithm is not very efficient/smart. I understand that for a larger time bracket, I need to decrease the number of time samples. However, I would like to know if there is any possible way of achieving this without compromising on time samples?

---

**SQL QUERY REFERENCE**

```
SELECT sensors.device_id, events.arrival_time, events.departure_time, events.duration
FROM events, sensors
WHERE
    STR_TO_DATE(arrival_time, '%d/%m/%Y %r') >= STR_TO_DATE(:start_time,'%d/%m/%Y %r') &&
    STR_TO_DATE(arrival_time, '%d/%m/%Y %r') <= STR_TO_DATE(:end_time,'%d/%m/%Y %r') &&
    events.device_id = sensors.device_id &&
    sensors.street_name= :street_name &&
    sensors.street_1 = :street_1 &&
    sensors.street_2 = :street_2
```

**PHP CODE REFERENCE**

```
//TIME RANGE
$start_time = "10/10/2011 12:00:00 AM";
$end_time = "11/10/2011 12:00:00 AM";

//SETUP ARRAYS FOR PLOTTING
$x_time = array();
$y_occupancy = array();

//ITERATE THROUGH TIME
for($i=strtotime($start_time); $i<=strtotime($end_time);$i+=60) {

    $current_time =  date("d/m/Y h:i:s A",$i); echo "<br>";

    $current_occupancy = 0;

    //ITERATE THROUGH SENSORS
    foreach($sensors as $sensor) {

        //ITERATIVE THROUGH EVENTS
        foreach($events as $event) {

            //CHECK IF THIS SENSOR IS ACTIVE AT THIS EVENT
            if (($sensor->device_id == $event->device_id) && (strtotime($current_time) >= strtotime($event->arrival_time) && strtotime($current_time) <= strtotime($event->departure_time))) {
                $current_occupancy++;
            }

        }//end event iterations

    }// end sensor iterations

    $x_time[] = $current_time;
    $y_occupancy[] = $current_occupancy;

}// end time iterationS



//SHOW TIME VS OCCUPANCY
for($i=0; $i<count($x_time);$i++) {
    echo $x_time[$i]; echo " "; echo $y_occupancy[$i]; echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: instead of repeated strtotime calls, why not operate on unix timestamps? you don't seem to actually need them.

Comment: @eis The time data in SQL table is stored as VARCHAR. I thought I need to convert string dates to actual time for conditionals to work.

Comment: So basically you have a list of time interval series [arrival, departure] and you would like to know for a particular time t how many time intervals it intersects?

Comment: This can be done efficiently using a min heap. Basically use a loop, and pop the min time of the heap. If the min time is an arrival time, increment count by 1 (1 car has arrived) and push the corresponding departure time on the heap. Else the time is a departure time and decrement count by 1, and push the next arrival time in that series onto the heap. Continue until the heap is empty.

Comment: @JasonL Thanks. Sadly, my PHP knowledge is quite limited and I partly understand what you have suggested. Can you give me a code example based on my PHP reference code so I can picture the algorithm in action?

Comment: I am no PHP programmer so I will provide some pseudocode. See my answer below.

Comment: @Jason L thanks for the detailed response. I will try to make sense of this algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct MyIterator
{
    Iterator i;
    DateTime t;
}

struct DataPoint
{
    DateTime t;
    int count;
}

List<DataPoint> CalculateIntervalCount(List<List<Interval>> series)
{
    initialise min-heap H
    foreach (List<Interval> S in series)
    {
        Iterator i=S.begin();
        H.push(new MyIterator(i, i.ArrivalTime));
    }
    int count=0;
    List<DataPoint> result=new List<DataPoint>();
    while(!H.emtpy())
    {
        Iterator min= H.pop();
        if(min.t==min.i.ArrivalTime)
        {
            ++count;
            result.Add(new DataPoint(min.t, count));
            H.push(new MyIterator(min.i, i.DepartureTime);
        }
        else 
        {
            --count;
            result.Add(new DataPoint(min.t, count));
            if (can advance min.i)
            {
                H.push(new MyIterator(min.i, i.ArrivalTime);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Explanation:

CalculateIntervalCount is a function which takes a list of interval series and return a series which gives the count of intervals at time t.

Assuming you have a "standard" iterator construct to a list and the iterator knows how to advance itself and knows how to check if it reaches the end, MyIterator is a wrap around the "standard" iterator with an additional DateTime field which either takes on the value of the ArrivalTime or DepartureTime of an interval.

The min heap H uses the MyIterator.t for comparison between two MyIterator objects.

The algorithm just implements what I have described in my comment. It should run in O(n lg k) time, where k is the number of interval series, n is the number of intervals in total across all series.